# Angularjs 2 RC5 Form can not be loaded

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

This is pretty annoying issue for the form.
My package.json is:

```
 "dependencies": {

     "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",

     "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",

    "systemjs": "0.19.36",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
```

But when I am using this:

```
import { FormsModule }      from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
```

It is dispatching error and can not find the form. Also I am not seeing FormsModule anymore in angular/forms directory.

Can anyone help to show me how you are importing forms in angular2?

I tried this one:

```
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES }      from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FORM_DIRECTIVES ],
```

But now in my webConsole, I did see:

```
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:3010/node_modules/@angular/forms@0.3.0//bundles/forms.umd.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Why it keeps adding 0.3.0 to the forms name? it should be:

```
http://localhost:3010/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js
```

Comment: What does your systemjs.config.js look like? The reason I'm asking is because it is in this file the address of the forms module is resolved (as well as for other modules).

Comment: Got it, I was this:  '@angular/forms':             'node_modules/@angular/forms' + formsVer, but after I change it to:  '@angular/forms':             'node_modules/@angular/forms', it is now good. Thans

Answer (score 0):

//In app.module.ts

//For data-dirven forms -->

```
import { DataDrivenComponent } from "./data-driven/data-driven.component";
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

//Other neccessary imports

```
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

//Ng module

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, DataDrivenComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

//Export class

```
export class AppModule {}
```